# Error occurred with NSURLConnection via 3G

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, 3g-network

I am using the IOS sdk to upload file, works fine over Wifi, but over 3G sometimes on large files the following error is caught in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)anError .....
```

"NSURLErrorDomain -1021 request body stream exhausted".

I know i can override this problem by implementing the method:

```
- (NSInputStream*)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *) request
```

so i did it. But when this method called i caught in didFailWithError next error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot allocate memory".

This error disappears if I add to method needNewBodyStream some delay. 
Can somebody explain me for what need this delay, and how can i get rid of this hack?

here is my code:

```
- (void) startUpload    
{    
   NSInputStream* fileStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath: sourcePath];

   [self.request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

   [self.request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%lu", fileSize] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

   [self.request setHTTPBodyStream: fileStream];

   NSURLConnection* newConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: self.request delegate: self startImmediately: YES];

   self.connection = newConnection;

   [newConnection release];
   [fileStream release];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (NSInputStream *) connection: (NSURLConnection *) aConnection needNewBodyStream: (NSURLRequest *) request
{
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 2];

   NSInputStream* fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath: sourcePath];

   if (fileStream == nil)
   {
       NSLog(@"NSURLConnection was asked to retransmit a new body stream for a request. Returning nil will cancel the connection.");
   }

   return fileStream;
}
```

Comment: Please reassure me the sleep is purely while debugging

Comment: How are you calculating fileSize? Sure that your Content-Length header is correct?

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't add to post. fileSize is calculating in method - (void) startUpload `NSDictionary* fileAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath: sourcePath error: &error];
unsigned long long fileSize = [fileAttribs fileSize];` I'm debugging on device IPad2 with 3G.